# Invalid option '6' for /langversion; must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default after running

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-config

I changed my .NET version of my project and now I am getting this error :

[image]

> Compiler Error Message: CS1617: Invalid option '6' for /langversion;
>   must be ISO-1, ISO-2, 3, 4, 5 or Default

Here is my web.config:

```
  <compilers>
          <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:5/nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
          </compiler>
          <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+">
            <providerOption name="CompilerVersion" value="v4.0"/>
          </compiler>
        </compilers>
```

Does anyone know what this means?

Answer (score 0):

Change to the `langversion:6` in `compilerOptions`

```
<compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeProvider, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6/nowarn:1659;1699;1701">
```